# Unable to publish maps via GeoServer because of wrong projection system

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

2022 layer upload shows this error any ideas?

> Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:900914" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "IdentifiedObject".

Adding more deatils from the duplicate ticket:

We are using GDAL ogr2pgr commpand to read shapefiles and load into a PostGIS DB.

The prj file associated with the shape file is in EPSG4326 WGS-84

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

When we use GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28 with the shapefile with prj the SRID in the PostGIS DB is EPSG 4326 and is published via the GeoServer.

But When we use GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27 with the same shapefile with prj the SRID in the PostGIS DB is EPS 900914 (Google I guess) I am unable to publish it via the GeoServer.

What is the issue here? Why is the SRID different in GDAl 3.0.4 and GDAL 3.4.1

The PostGIS version is 3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1 The PostgreSQL version is 14.2 (Ubuntu 14.2-1.pgdg20.04+1)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. If possible, please open your file(raster/vector) in QGIS, check its projection, and if it is missing, add the projection and save your data set.
Again open the same file, if is it working fine then its good to publish it on Geoserver

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439509/importing-geopackages-epsg900913-into-postgresql-postgis-shows-up-as-900914?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C54.6409 help?

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS the project shows just fine as EPSG 4326 and that is right. Somehow the GDAL version 3.4 seems to read this as 900914 and that is not publishable via the Geoserver.

[image]