# GDAL identifying SRID from prj in shapefiles

Tags: postgis, gdal, shapefile

We are using GDAL ogr2pgr commpand to read shapefiles and load into a PostGIS DB.

The prj file associated with the shape file is in EPSG4326 WGS-84

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

When we use GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28 with the shapefile with prj the SRID in the PostGIS DB is EPSG 4326 and is published via the GeoServer.

But
When we use GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27 with the same shapefile with prj the SRID in the PostGIS DB is EPS 900914 (Google I guess) I am unable to publish it via the GeoServer.

What is the issue here?
Why is the SRID different in GDAl 3.0.4 and GDAL 3.4.1

The PostGIS version is 3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
The PostgreSQL version is 14.2 (Ubuntu 14.2-1.pgdg20.04+1)

The error that we get is
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:900914" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "IdentifiedObject".

Comment: please [edit] your original question to improve it rather than posting a new one

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439509/importing-geopackages-epsg900913-into-postgresql-postgis-shows-up-as-900914?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C54.6409